# In PHP shell_exec function with command "node welcome.js" does not return value

Tags: php

The `welcome.js` code is given below

```
console.log('Wellcome');
```

and the php file code is given below

```
$op = shell_exec('node welcome.js').PHP_EOL;
echo $op
```

If I run the php file in command line it print Wellcome but when I run from browser it does not print any output.

Answer (score 2):

There are most likely errors here that you're not seeing.

1. Set 'error_reporting' to -1 and 'display_errors' to 1 in your php.ini and be sure to restart your webserver/fastcgi-listeners. This is more reliable than using ini_set() and error_reporting() in the script, which will fail if there are parse errors...see [php:errorfunc.configuration](http://php.net/errorfunc.configuration) for more detail.
2. Check the appropriate error log (depending on your settings and the Server API, this can be the httpd's error log, syslog, some independent file, or even going nowhere right now). Again, [php:errorfunc.configuration](http://php.net/errorfunc.configuration) can help you get things configured correctly, or suss out the current configuration.
3. The $PATH (or %PATH% on Win32) for an interactive login session is usually dramatically different than that of a running daemon. Try specifying the full path to the node binary.
4. I don't know off-hand which file-handle node's "console.log()" goes out to. Assuming you're using a bourne-style shell (such as bash) for the subshell here, you can try piping stderr to stdout, using something like: `$op = shell_exec('/foo/bin/node welcome.js 2>&1').PHP_EOL; echo $op;`
5. Make sure that 'welcome.js' is where you think it is in relation to the current working directory of your PHP process (although it's likely that node would warn you via one of the previous suggestions if this were not the case, it seemed worth pointing out as a potential pitfall.)

Comment: hi @NarendraGirase if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark.